# Javascript: failed in creating a node on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

[image]

I am a beginner in Javascript, started learning it 2 days ago because I wanted to set up some cloud functions on Firebase. The database structure of my app (already published) is shown in the figure, and what I want is:

When users upload their "achievements" to Firebase, the cloud function calculates "the total times" that a specific achievement has been achieved by all users. For example, achievements[0] is achieved 80000 times in total, and achievements[28] is achieved 54321 times in total. After calculating them, I store the array under the node "achievementsCount_total", which would be at the same level as the node "users".

To do this, I followed the documents on Firebase and tried to accomplish the cloud function. Here are the codes:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.updateScores = functions.database.ref('/users/{userUID}/achievements')
.onWrite(event => {
  var database=firebase.database();
  var achievementsCount_total=new Array();
  for(var i=0;i<60;i++){achievementsCount_total[i]=0;}
  var allUsersSnapshot = event.data.parent.parent.child('/{userUID}');//a list containing all users
  allUsersSnapshot.forEach(function(element) {
    var achievements_this = element.child('/achievements').val();
    for(var i=0;i<60;i++)
    {
      achievementsCount_total[i]+=achievements_this[i];
    }
  }, this);
  database.ref('achievementsCount_total').set(achievementsCount_total);
  return null;
});
```

However, the new node("achievementsCount_total") was not created at the same level as "users". I checked it on Firebase and found that the function was successfully executed, while the new node did not show up. Please help me with what I did wrong. Thank u~

Comment: Start changing 

var achievementsCount_total=new Array();
for(var i=0;i<60;i++){achievementsCount_total[i]=0;}

to

var achievementsCount_total= [];
for(var i=0;i<60;i++){achievementsCount_total.push(0);}

Comment: Nope. I think the problem is that I couldn't even add the node to the database.